# How user can use database without having DBMS

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm new to the topic of databases and DBMS.

I have written the PhoneBook program with C# .NET and SQL Server.

My question is how can I run this program on a users computer who hasn't got SQL Server?

I want when they click on the execution file on their computer, it will work immediately and correctly and they can store new users or delete some user

Comment: The answer is you can't.

Comment: @DaleK So how other programs like this can do that?

Comment: You have to install SQL Server. You wouldn't normally use SQL Server for a small single user application. You normally use SQL Server on a server where it is accessed by multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could host a SQL server for your users and require they have an internet connection.

You could rewrite it as a web application, also requiring an internet connection.

Or you can use [SQLite](https://sqlite.org), an embedded SQL client and, for lack of a better term, server. That's what I'd recommend, and that's what many applications do. SQLite is not fully compatible with SQL Server, so you'd have to rewrite some of your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation
What do other applications like mobile Phone Book or Contacts do for solving this problem?
Do they use your method or they Save Data in some Particular files?

Comment: @DariushStony I'm not a mobile developer, but it's my understanding they use SQLite or other embedded database. iOS has CoreData. Things like contacts are provided by the OS. See https://greenrobot.org/news/mobile-databases-sqlite-alternatives-and-nosql-for-android-and-ios/